# How to load custom xml files during docker run?

Tags: java, docker, spring-boot

I have a two custom xml property files that are environment specific used in my spring boot project. Is it possible to use mount or volume tag to get the files from a location specified during docker run? The xml files are required to successfully connect to a db server.

Also if I specify an env-file command in the docker run can i put my sh files in any location on the docker server and specify the path there in the run command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do that by mounting a volume. It will swap your in-container location with chosen server location. Inside container there will be no difference between this shared location and any other. Use flag -v "SERVER_LOCATION:CONTAINER_LOCATION":

```
docker run -v /etc/xmlsFolder:/etc/appConfig/destinationFolder your_image
```

Yes, you can specify run command in script anywhere on server.